# File I/O issues in multithreaded code

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, critical-section

I secure my thread function in class with `CRITICAL_SECTION` and do a lot
of Send/Receive socket actions and everything is OK, but if threads are writing to log file I'm getting into troubles!

**h**

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA();    
    ~ClassA();

    void run();
    ...

private:
    CRITICAL_SECTION criticalSection;
    LogFiles *m_logFiles;
    ...
};
```

**cpp**

```
ClassA::ClassA()
{
    m_logFiles = new LogFiles();
    InitializeCriticalSection(&criticalSection);
}

ClassA::~ClassA()
{
    delete m_logFiles;
    DeleteCriticalSection(&criticalSection);
}

void ClassA::run()
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&criticalSection); 

    // do some stuff
    m_logFiles->WriteToFile(message);
    // do some stuff
    m_logFiles->WriteToFile(message);

    LeaveCriticalSection(&criticalSection);
}
```

Logfile contains not all information (only data from e.g. 2 of 4 threads), or overwritten lines (2 threads wrote at the same time)!

So I think I also have to secure the WriteToFile method in LogFiles?!

Thanks for any help and/or example!

Comment: Are you sure that you use the single (the same) object of class A in each thread?

Comment: All your threads should `lock/unlock` the same `CRITICAL_SECTION` object. Are you sure they do?

Comment: @AnatolyS: yes, all threads are using the same ClassA object

Comment: @leon22 in this case extra information with details is welcome

Comment: What's `CRITICAL_SECTION`?

Comment: @HAL this is light mutex in Windows

Comment: @HAL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @leon22 Please consider adding an appropriate tag to suggest `Windows` library/platform.

Comment: @leon22 Independent of your issue here, it would make a lot of sense to make your logger `LogFiles` thread-safe.

Comment: There's apparently a problem with locking or your understanding thereof. Once you fix it though, you might also want to change the way you open your log files: if you specify FILE_APPEND_DATA and omit FILE_WRITE_DATA as desired access, you'll get atomic appends.

Comment: What you describe doesn't seem possible. You're absolutely certain that they're all using the same *instance* of `ClassA`? What happens if you make that `CRITICAL_SECTION` object static so that there can be only one of them?

Comment: Show your `WriteToFile` method.  Are you flushing the writes or closing the file each time?  If not, there's your problem.

Comment: @CareyGregory: Why would lack of flushing be a problem? As long as it's the same file handle and only one thread is writing to it at a time, there should be no problem with the buffer becoming corrupt.

Comment: @JimMischel - That's why I want to see the logging class.  How do we know it's the same handle?

Answer (score 5):

Because the `CRITICAL_SECTION` is an instance variable, each `ClassA` object effectively has its own, independent mutex.  As a result, one object locking the mutex (aka entering the critical section) does not prevent any other object from doing the same to its private mutex, and the common log file resource is completely unprotected.

You can fix this by making the `CRITICAL_SECTION` class-static or otherwise global, and intializing it during program startup.

A better choice might be for the `LogFiles` class to maintain its own CRITICAL_SECTION (or even better, one for each log file that it manages), and have the `WriteToFile()` function explicitly lock/unlock (aka enter/leave) it internally when called.  This way the resource could protect itself, rather than explicitly requiring its users to do so.  It would thus always behave correctly and it would lower the burden on the users of the `LogFile` class.

Comment: This would seem the obvious problem but the OP states in the comments that all threads are using a single instance of the class object.  He has not explained how he does so.

Answer (score 0):

Either wrap accesses to the logfile with a mutex (like win32's CRITICAL_SECTION) or use a separate thread to write logfile entries. In other words, the sketch you provide is correct as far as multithreading is concerned.

There are other big issues with your code though. Firstly, stop using pointers, in particular don't write Java/C# code like "Type* t = new Type();" all over the place. This only increases complexity and causes memory leaks. Secondly, you have to control copying and assignment of your self-defined types. Your class ClassA for example is copyable, but the instances are not independent, which leads to further subtle bugs (dangling pointers, memory leaks etc).

If fixing the C++ issues doesn't help, consider stripping down the code to a minimal example that demonstrates the problem and post it here.